# How to plot graph by arrays using pyplot in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I'm studying about building the GCN and now i implement this code below.

I run it on jupyternotebook.

In [1]

```
import numpy as np
from networkx import karate_club_graph, to_numpy_matrix
zkc = karate_club_graph()
order = sorted(list(zkc.nodes()))
A = to_numpy_matrix(zkc, nodelist=order)
I = np.eye(zkc.number_of_nodes())
A_hat = A + I
D_hat = np.array(np.sum(A_hat, axis=0))[0]
D_hat = np.matrix(np.diag(D_hat))
```

In [2]

```
X = np.matrix([
        [i, -i]
        for i in range(A.shape[0])
    ], dtype=float)
```

In [3]

```
 W = np.matrix([
         [1, -1],
         [-1, 1]
     ])
```

In [4]

```
  W_1 = np.random.normal(
    loc=0, scale=1, size=(zkc.number_of_nodes(), 4))
  W_2 = np.random.normal(
    loc=0, size=(W_1.shape[1], 2))
```

In [5]

```
  def gcn_layer(A_hat, D_hat, X, W):
      return D_hat**-1 * A_hat * X * W
  H_1 = gcn_layer(A_hat, D_hat, I, W_1)
  H_2 = gcn_layer(A_hat, D_hat, H_1, W_2)
      output = H_2
```

In [6]

```
 feature_representations = {
  node: np.array(output)[node] 
  for node in zkc.nodes()}
```

This is all code and i want to create graph like this but i don't know how to plot it by using arrays 
on matplotlib.pyplot thankyou.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc9uD.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried with a simple scatter plot? It works just fine with arrays https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to plot values from *feature_representations*, but the problem is that it is dictionary where values are arrays. In order to use matplotlib.pyplot.scatter properly (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), you have to convert your dictionary to two arrays that can be passed as x and y arguments.

Maybe try the following code in the [7] cell:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
arrays = feature_representations.values()
X = [el[0] for el in arrays]
Y = [el[0] for el in arrays]
plt.scatter(X, Y)
```

It gives the following output:

[image]